# Proxy Activity for wrapping multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

Since often in Android some functionality is directly implemented in an Activity (e.g. NativeActivity) I am now faced with the situation, that I have 2 Activities that I would like to be "*merged*" into one because I need both functionality.
So my initial idea would be to write a Proxy Activity, which delegates to internal Activity instances. Is something similar already possible in Android or might this concept even work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried implementing an Activity-Proxy which would delegate to other Activities (which would have to use the same `Window`, `WindowManager`, etc.).
Sadly, it does not work since the `Activity.attach` methods are `final`/`package` and they are used for setting up all the internal variables. These variables are then used directly (without a `protected` or `public` getter). So with no chance to mend the internals you cannot force all Activities to use the same context and thus you are forced to reimplement the functionality the Activities provide. :(

Comment: For us the solution was to cut pre Android 4.0 support.

Answer (score -2):

Use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).
I think this is what you are looking for...

Comment: It is not since there is e.g. no NativeFragment. The problem is that the code is in the Activities and nowhere else.

Comment: Move all your code to a fragment class and in activity layout just use  that fragment.

Comment: The problem is NOT my code but the code of the Android platform. E.g. I want to use the Native* interface, but can only use it in the form of an Activity. That then rules out using other Activity implementations. We now solved this by only supporting Android 4.0 upwards, where everything is implemented in the `Activity` class.

Comment: Sorry, maybe this is because of my poor english but i dont understand you. By "Native interface" you mean that you using NDK and writing on C++? If so then sorry, you should add "android-ndk" tag to your question.